# How to check first child of a list has `selected` class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

My list:

```
<div id="menu1" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#home" class="home_link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about_us">about us</a></li>
        <li><a class="next" href="#features">features</a></li>
        <li><a class="next" href="#news">news</a></li>
        <li><a class="next" href="#gallery">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a class="next" href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to check if first child of the link is selected or not. Something like below:

```
if ($('div#menu1 ul:first-child').hasClass('selected'))
```

please help me out?

Comment: In the future, if you need to do some simple things with jQuery, you should probably start with the official [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) which is very well-written and well-organized. It would have been pretty easy to find a solution to your problem by looking through it.

Comment: You should provide more details. HTML and JQuery posted here aren't sufficient, obviously. You got few correct answers, but it is still ''not working''. Obviously - something is missing here....

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#menu1").find("li").first().hasClass('selected')
```

Try the above code.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code bro.. this solution must work fine.

Comment: i also feel that. by the way thanks for your help all you guys.

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery first-child selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) documentation, first-child, *Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.* So
Try this:

```
   if ($('div#menu1 ul li: first-child').hasClass('selected'))
```

**Edit:**

I Created a fiddle and it's working fine. [Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/0owvwdrm/). remember to put above code inside `$(document).ready()` function. Also make sure that you've included jquery properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkClass = $('#menu1 ul li:first-child').hasClass('selected');
if(checkClass) {
    alert('selected');
}
else{
    alert('not selected');
}
```

Comment: I have not downvoted, but Have't you seen the warning message? __Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.__

Comment: not working again. i think something is preventing it to happen. but else condition is executing well.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the selector `:first` which you should use it as:

```
alert($('#menu1 ul li:first').hasClass('selected'));
```